# Parsing a string in c++ with a specfic format

Tags: c++, string

I have this string `post "ola tudo bem como esta" alghero.jpg` and i want to break it into 3 pieces `post`, `ola tudo bem como esta` (i dont want the "") and `alghero.jpg` i tried it in c because im new and not really good at programming in c++ but its not working. Is there a more efficient way of doing this in c++?

Program:

```
int main()
{
    char* token1 = new char[128];
    char* token2 = new char[128];
    char* token3 = new char[128];
    char str[] = "post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg";
    char *token;
   
    /* get the first token */
    token = strtok(str, " ");
    //walk through other tokens
    while( token != NULL ) {
        printf( " %s\n", token );
        
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `std::stringstream` may help

Comment: Using `std::string` you can use `find` and `substr`.

Comment: but how really?

Comment: When you say you need to parse something, it is important to be clear about how you expect the data to be formatted. That is, if you just want to parse the one string then you can hardcode the result so presumably you want to parse other strings with the same form as `post "ola tudo bem como esta" alghero.jpg`. What can we expect of those strings? always a triple separated by single spaces of like <unquoted string> <quoted string> <unquoted string>?

Comment: yes i want to parse strings in the format <unquoted string> <quoted string> <unquoted string> but i dont want the quotes of the quoted string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++14 and later, you can use [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) to read quoted strings from any `std::istream`, such as `std::istringstream`, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::string token1, token2, token3;
    std::string str = "post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg";
   
    std::istringstream(str) >> token1 >> std::quoted(token2) >> token3;

    std::cout << token1 << "\n";
    std::cout << token2 << "\n";
    std::cout << token3 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` to find the positions of the 2 quotes. Use `substr` to get the string from index 0 to first quote, first quote to second quote, and second quote to end.

```
std::string s = "post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg";
auto first = s.find('\"');
if (first != s.npos) {
    auto second = s.find('\"', first + 1);
    if (second != s.npos) {
        std::cout << s.substr(0, first-1) << '\n';
        std::cout << s.substr(first+1, second-first-1) << '\n';
        std::cout << s.substr(second+2) << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
post
ola tudo bem como esta
alghero.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

One option for parsing strings is using regular expressions, for example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

// struct to hold return value of parse function
struct parse_result_t
{
    bool parsed{ false };
    std::string token1;
    std::string token2;
    std::string token3;
};

// the parse function
auto parse(const std::string& string)
{
    // this is a regex 
    // ^ match start of line
    // (.*)\\\" matches any character until a \" (escaped ") and then escaped again for C++ string
    // \w+ match one or more whitepsaces
    // (.*)$ match 0 or more characters until end of string
    // see it live here : https://regex101.com/r/XnkAZV/1
    static std::regex rx{ "^(.*?)\\s+\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\s+(.*)$" };

    std::smatch match;
    parse_result_t result;

    if (std::regex_search(string, match, rx))
    {
        result.parsed = true;
        result.token1 = match[1];
        result.token2 = match[2];
        result.token3 = match[3];
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = parse("post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg");

    std::cout << "parse result = " << (result.parsed ? "success" : "failed") << "\n";
    std::cout << "token 1 = " << result.token1 << "\n";
    std::cout << "token 2 = " << result.token2 << "\n";
    std::cout << "token 3 = " << result.token3 << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the strings are always separated by a single space you can just find the first space and last space using `std::string::find` and std::string::rfind`, split on those characters, and unquote the middle string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

std::string unquote(const std::string& str) {
    if (str.front() != '"' || str.back() != '"') {
        return str;
    }
    return str.substr(1, str.size() - 2);
}

std::tuple < std::string, std::string, std::string> parse_triple_with_quoted_middle(const std::string& str) {
    auto iter1 = str.begin() + str.find(' ');
    auto iter2 = str.begin() + str.rfind(' ');

    auto str1 = std::string(str.begin(),iter1);
    auto str2 = std::string(iter1 + 1, iter2);
    auto str3 = std::string(iter2 + 1, str.end() );

    return { str1, unquote(str2), str3 };
}

int main()
{
    std::string test = "post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg";
    auto [str1, str2, str3] = parse_triple_with_quoted_middle(test);
    std::cout << str1 << "\n";
    std::cout << str2 << "\n";
    std::cout << str3 << "\n";
}
```

You should probably put more input validation into the above, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for this:

- The pattern to search repeatedly for would be: optionally starting with whitespaces `\s*`; then `([^\"]*)` zero or more characters other than quotes (zero or more because you could have several quotes one after the other); and we capture this group (hence the use of parentheses); and finally, whether a quote `\"` or `|` the end of the expression `$`; and we don't capture this group `(:?)`.
  We use `std::regex` to store the pattern, wrapping it all within `R"()"`, so that we can write the raw expression.
- The `while` loop does a few things: it searches the next match with `regex_search`, extracts the captured group, and updates the input line, so that the next search will start where the current one finished.
  `matches` is an array whose first element, `matches[0]`, is the part of `line` matching the whole pattern, and the next elements correspond to the pattern's captured groups.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/caP41GYWz)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <regex>  // regex_search, smatch

int main() {
    std::string line{"post \"ola tudo bem como esta\" alghero.jpg"};
    std::regex pattern{R"(\s*([^\"]*)(:?\"|$))"};
    std::smatch matches{};
    while (std::regex_search(line, matches, pattern))
    {
         std::cout << matches[1] << "\n";
         line = matches.suffix();
    }
}
```